# Convert date to ISO format sql server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, date-format, iso

I've date like this `$input = '19/02/2013'`.

How do I insert this date in my table (ISO 8601 format)?

Platform is SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008.

Comment: the topic they claim is a duplicate seems to provide a solution to an unsupported version of PHP, the solutions provided below are more current and sufficiently better advice than the other topic.

Answer (score 1):

Think this should do it.

```
$dt = new DateTime(strtotime($input));
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some php functions to convert to sqlserver date format

```
$input = 19/02/2013;
$new_date = explode('/',$input);
$date = $new_date[2]-$new_date[1]-$new_date[0];
```

For ISO format you can use like this

```
$date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: $newdate = date ('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$input))); /* format iSO ..*/ but I got an error when I try to insert this date on my table ... ]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. ) )